# .htaccess not loading, even after httpd.conf changes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was trying to fiddle with wordpress permalinks the other day, and they weren't working. (returning 404s due to not reading the .htaccess under a nested .htaccess) After a little Googling, I decided I needed `AllowOverride All`. (I'm using Apache on a local server).

I went to my httpd.conf and changed every `AllowOverride` I could find to `All`. I also uncommented the `rewrite_module` line. I saved and restarted the server. The .htaccess is still not coming back. The whole problem is getting this file to load, and I'm pretty sure then everything will be fine, but as I'm no Apache conf file expert, I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your paths and document root is setup correctly? What happens when you go to `http://your.domain.com/wordpress/.htaccess`, where `/wordpress` is the path to where your wordpress install is?

Comment: Check the <virtualhost> section in the `sites-available` directory. Also, what do you use inside the htaccess to test if it is working?

Comment: I was putting random asdf's in there but it wasn't affecting the page. I have been toying with the virtual hosts recently (which also don't work) but how might that be a problem?

Comment: Is the .htaccess readable for the Apache process? Try comparing file permissions for the working and the not working .htaccess and maybe change the permissions for the nested .htaccess

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 unfortunately, and cannot easily get to the permissions as a number. As far as I can tell with the system though, they seem to be the same, except for the fact that WP's htaccess has an administrator symbol near the edit button for the permissions, whereas my doesn't. I really never bothered with this as I work locally mostly.

Comment: What exactly are you running? Win7 with Apache? We'd need more info to help correctly. But, first thing to check is if the mod_rewrite module is even being loaded.

Comment: I am using Win7 with Apache. How might I figure out if mod_rewrite is being loaded?